# Disable distributed tracing for development

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, distributed-tracing

We are setting up microservice framework.

We use following stack for distributed tracing.

- Spring boot
- Kafka
- Zipkin

Following is how the configuration is done

In `gradle.build` (or pom.xml) following starter dependencies added

```
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka'
```

Add one AlwaysSampler bean

```
@Bean
public Sampler defaultSampler() {
    return Sampler.ALWAYS_SAMPLE;
}
```

If we have `kafka` running, things work automatically.

But if kafka is not running, server does not start - this is mostly the case for development environment.

If I want to stop this, I have to comment out all the code mentioned here (as we use starter dependency with spring boot, it automatically configures as I understand).

Can we just make some changes in properties (or yaml) files so that I don't need to go and comment out all these code?

Or probably another way to disable this without doing some commenting, etc.

Answer (score 26):

You can add the following setting on your properties key to disable zipkin, [source](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/3.1.x/spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/zipkin2/ZipkinProperties.java#L56).

```
spring.zipkin.enabled=false
```

Better yet, create separate development properties (like `application-dev.properties`) to avoid changing above setting everytime you want to run in your machine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34846351/4504053

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Boot 3, this would be:

```
management.tracing.enabled=false
```