# How to disable zipkin reporter in spring boot 3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, zipkin, micrometer-tracing

In spring boot 2 it was possible to disable distributed tracing during development as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56529683/10674026). Locally, traces were still generated but not exported.

In spring boot 3 it is possible it **disable tracing at all** with:

```
     management.tracing.enabled=false
```

**How can I disable the zipkin reporter or distributed tracing in spring boot 3 but keep local tracing on?**

Comment: You have to exclude `io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-brave` dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe by setting [this property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.actuator.management.tracing.sampling.probability) to 0.0?

```
management.tracing.sampling.probability: 0.0
```

Comment: This actualy doesn't help. App anyway tries to send spans to zipkin url at first call.

Answer (score 2):

After going through a lot of posts, I concluded that it is not supported to-date. So the workaround that I have for now have three pieces

1.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = ZipkinAutoConfiguration.class)
public class SomeSpringApplication {
    ....
}
```

2. 

```
@Configuration
@Import(ZipkinAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "management.tracing.zipkin", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class ZipKinEnvConfig {
}
```

3. In your properties file:

   management.tracing.zipkin.enabled=false

If this property exists as false, local traces will work and not sent to Zipkin. If this property is true or not existing, traces will be sent out. I believe this is the same behavior as Spring 2.X property. The only annoying part to make this generic is the annotation on SpringBootApplication file :(

Answer (score 2):

You can disable zipkin via spring config:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.tracing.zipkin.ZipkinAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be removed in Spring Boot 3 with Micrometer. It was used to be available in spring-cloud-sleuth.

Anyone see any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Check and remove this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or any other reporter dependency...