# Setting properties in Spring Boot project for deployment to Google App Engine

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine

I have a Spring Boot application that I'm looking to deploy to deploy to Google App Engine.

During development I set a number of values in my `application.properties` file (example below), found in `src\main\resources`. It seems that I need to store these values in a `yaml` file for GAE, but I haven't been able to find any documentation/examples of how to do this. I know there needs to be an `app.yaml` file and environment variables can be set it in, but are the `application.properties` values environment variables?

Also, I'd ideally like to be able to use the same setup for both production and development, but have different values (e.g. db connection values) depending on whether the app is in prod or development. Is that possible?

*src\main\resources\application.properties*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://my_db_host:my_db_port/my_db_name
spring.datasource.username=my_username
spring.datasource.password=my_password
myapp.app.jwtExpirationMs= 3600000
myapp.app.refreshTokenExpirationMs= 2419200000
spring.mail.username = my_email@gmail.com
# etc etc
```

*src\main\appengine\app.yaml*

```
runtime: java11

instance_class: B1

basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 4
```

Comment: Any update on this? I have similar issue in that I'm getting a communication exception to MySql when I deploy on google cloud but connection to database works find when run locally.

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie199 It turns out that you don't need to store the properties in `app.yaml`, they can stay in `applications.properties`. For prod/dev setup, I used this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845990/spring-use-one-application-properties-for-production-and-another-for-debug

Comment: @OD1995, please post your answer so that it would be helpful for other community members with similar questions such as yours.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered you don't actually need to put your `application.properties` in an `app.yaml` file, they can stay in `application.properties`.

For having a dev/prod setup, this answered my question: [Spring use one application.properties for production and another for debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845990/spring-use-one-application-properties-for-production-and-another-for-debug)